# Why is King Herod's song ragtime?

Tags: soundtrack, jesus-christ-superstar

According to [this answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/7441/6802), in [Jesus Christ Superstar (1973), King Herod's song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9ALiADrJro) is in ragtime style.

**Is there any reason or symbolism for choosing such a style for the song?**

Comment: While an interesting question, this seems to be ultimately a question about the musical not really related to its film adaptation, no? Or did the film employ a different musical style than the actual musical?

Comment: Nonetheless it seems to be already answered in the link you added to your question

Comment: I ask about the symbolical reason for using such style. I the linked question they only explain what's the style, but not why the director would chose this style for representing King Herod.

Comment: The film adaptation was made 2 years after the musical opened on Broadway.  The (film) director was making no artistic choices here in the choice of this style of music.

Answer (score 1):

[IMDB's trivia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070239/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv) has this to say about the song.

> "King Herod's Song" is based on "Those Saladin Days", from "Come Back, Richard, Your Country Needs You," a failed Andrew Lloyd Webber musical for schools about King Richard the Lion-Hearted and the Crusades. Tim Rice wrote new lyrics, first as 1969 Eurovision contender "Try It and See," and then as "King Herod's Song" for the album, show, and film.

So it could be said that they were trying to fit an already written piece of music into the show.